# Special characters in PDO select statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im asking this because I have been beating my head on a wall for a something that more than likely has a simple solution. My problem is that I am trying to select a record that contains a unique id similar to "ss&246i". If the statement doesnt contain an & symbol it returns just fine but if it has one I get no return. Here is my code to compliment my problem:

```
<?php
@session_start();

if (isset($_POST['code'])) {
    $id = $_POST['code'];
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example', 'example', '******');
    $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_human_readable WHERE unique_id = :id  LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id", $id);
    try {
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getCode() . " - " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $return = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($return);
    if ($return) {
        $_SESSION['code'] = $id;
        echo "success"; 
    } else {
        echo "failed";
    }
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

As always any help on this is very much appreciated

Comment: your query seems unusable to me, no matter what id is selected. What tutorial you're learning from? Anyway, no special characters could affect PDO query. So, your problem is somewhere else. Most likely some encoding problem or some useless "sanitize" function in effect.

Comment: Change `':id'` to `:id` in the query - the quoting is taken care of by `prepare`.

Comment: Meh... posted it with the single quotes wasnt intentional. Removed them from the SELECT statement as they are un-needed. Any ideas on why it is unusable? It works minus the & character.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, my guess would be that `&` is getting escaped or encoded somehow beforehand.  Do a var_dump($id) to check the string really is what you expect.

Comment: ahh found it doing the call through AJAX and therefore it is escaping the & character... Thanks for giving me the tip +therefromhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When solving problems, programmer have to employ *knowledge* and *experience*.

Knowledge will tell him that no special character could affect a properly formatted PDO query.
So, it's time to try some experience. Means one have not just staring at the code, but *run* it. On the purpose of verifying assumptions.

You're assuming that $_POST['code'] contains literal `ss&246i` value. But you cannot know if it's true or not - you never verified it. So, you have to place a verification code in your script to be sure.

You're assuming that database contains literal `ss&246i` value.  But you cannot know if it's true or not - you never verified it. So, you have to run some code to verify the assumption - try to select a hardcoded literal value instead of posted one.

This way, one by one, verify all your assumptions and find which ones are false. So, you'll be able to either solve the problem on your own or ask a meaningful question on Stack Overflow.

the above process is called *debugging* and being essential part of programmer's job.

Comment: Ill accept that considering its an obvious answer =P. Was on 48 hours no sleep crunch time so the logical debugging steps seemed to have slipped my mind. Common sense must have as well because it is obvious that properly debugging the code would have shown me what I was looking for.